# creating avd from command line with keyboard support

Tags: android, keyboard, android-virtual-device

How can I create avd from command line with keyboard support?

I was able to create avd from commandline using:
`android create avd`, but I dont know how to enable keyboard support into this.

Even android documentaion/help doesn't any thing about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure a AVD and launch the emulator via the documentation at [Managing AVDs from the command line](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/managing-avds-cmdline.html).

If you need a special hardware configuration, answer 'yes' at the "Do you wish to create a custom hardware profile" prompt and when creating the AVD, and then specify the hardware keyboard at the appropriate prompt.

Comment: This answer is outdated. The `android` tool is no longer supported. Jwsonic's answer works, though.

Answer (score 3):

The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/avd.html) for avd actually mentions that an avd has they keyboard turned on by default in the "Setting hardware emulation options" section. If you really want to ensure keyboard support from the command line, you could always edit the config.ini with a text editor like vim and set `hw.keyboard = "yes"`.

Comment: thats true but in my case emulator dosn't display keyboard though hw.keyboar=yes is there in config filr

Comment: Your link leads to a 404. Where would this config file go and how would it be referenced from the command line command?

Comment: In Linux, the `config.ini` file is located at `~/.android/avd/${DEVICE_NAME}.avd/config.ini`